# Выборка домена из ссылки

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Составил регулярку в perl-программе `^https?:\\/\\/([a-z0-9\\.\\-]+\\.[a-z0-9\\-]{2,12})/.*`, но необходимо её применить в си-программе.

1. В си не могу понять как выполнить данную реулярку, чтобы вытащить домен из ссылки. Использую код

   ```
       re=pcre_compile(regexp,0,&error,&erroffset,NULL);
       if (!re) continue;
       if (pcre_exec(re,NULL,link,strlen(link),0,0,ovector,sizeof(ovector))>0)
       {
        printf("%s\n",ovector);
       }
       pcre_free(re);
   ```
2. Сомневаюсь в правильности регулярки. Может чего не учел?

Comment: Уберите знак `^`. Вместо `.*` используйте `\S*`.

Comment: А чем лучше использовать \S* вместо .* ?

Comment: `\S` исключает из совпадения пробелы.

Comment: @nerik, на этом сайте уже обсуждались регулярки для доменных имен.

Comment: Еще перед последней `/` нет обратного слеша. А так в принципе ничего, если URL обычные, попробуйте в браузере например `http://1476101272/` на гугл попадете, но так писать конечно не принято :)

Comment: andy.37, вообще-то основной вопрос был по си ) А написание регулярки это дополнительно

Comment: @nerik И в pcre_exec последний параметр не размер массива подвыражений, а количество элементов в нем и оно должно быть кратно трем. Например `int ovector[9];  pcre_exec(....,9)` и с печатью явные проблемы. Это же массив int'ов - смещений подвыражений как я понял. детально не копал, я подвыражения никогда не использовал

Comment: @nerik Вот нашлось: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421785/how-can-i-use-pcre-to-get-all-match-groups

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, очень помогло

Answer (score 1):

Для разбора uri по rfc2068 я как-то использовал [такое](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI)

```
#define SPLIT_URI_REGEX \
  "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"
```

(не pcre) выражение.

Пример:

```
...
struct uri {
  char            *scheme,
    *net_loc,
    *path,
    *query,
    *fragment;
};
...


static regex_t reguri;
static pthread_mutex_t  reglock = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
static int     inireg = 0;

#define SPLIT_URI_REGEX \
  "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"
#define ISCHEME   2
#define INETLOC   4
#define IPATH     5
#define IQUERY    7
#define IFRAGMENT 8

static char *
mkuri_comp (char *uri, regmatch_t *p)
{
  if (p->rm_so < 0)
    return NULL;

  int  l = p->rm_eo - p->rm_so;
  char buf[4096];
  strncpy(buf, uri+p->rm_so, l);
  buf[l] = 0;
  return strdup(buf);
}

void
split_uri (char *uri, struct uri *suri)
{
  if (!inireg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&reglock);
    if (!inireg) {
      regcomp (&reguri, SPLIT_URI_REGEX, REG_EXTENDED);
      inireg = 1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&reglock);
  }
  regmatch_t match[reguri.re_nsub];
  if (regexec (&reguri, uri, reguri.re_nsub, match, 0) == 0) { // OK
    suri->scheme = mkuri_comp (uri,&match[ISCHEME]);
    suri->net_loc = mkuri_comp (uri,&match[INETLOC]);
    suri->path = mkuri_comp (uri,&match[IPATH]);
    suri->query = mkuri_comp (uri,&match[IQUERY]);
    suri->fragment = mkuri_comp (uri,&match[IFRAGMENT]);
  }
}
```

С предварительным обнулением полей `struct uri` перед вызовом `split_uri()`.

Comment: avp, спасибо, но слишком громоздко

Comment: @nerik, ну, вся мутота с pthreads locking Вам видимо не нужна. Соответственно, остается regcomp/regexec + взять данные из match[4]

Comment: спасибо попробую, но все равно хотелось бы именно с regexp разобраться

Comment: @nerik, если Вы о  pcre_compile/pcre_exec, то вот тут   http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcredemo.html есть пример использования.

Comment: о спасибо, буду разбирать